# Informatica IICS - passing in/out parameter values between two data flows in the same mapping job

Tags: parameters, parameter-passing, informatica-cloud

I have two data flows, that is, two piplines in the single mapping job. The execution of these pipelines is controlled by **Flow Run Order**.

The first pipeline is supposed to fetch *max ID* from database table and pass it to in-out parameter named **MaxIDParam**.

The second pipeline is supposed to take this *max ID* and do something with it. So, the in-out parameter **MaxIDParam** is assigned to output field **O_MaxID($$MaxIDParam)**.

The first pipeline is doing well, it is passing *max ID* from the database to parameter (**SetVariable($$MaxIDParam, Max_ID)**). The trouble is that this data never reaches to the second pipeline. **Instead of getting the **MaxIDParam** value from the current session, the second pipeline outputs the value from the previous session**, which I find a bit odd.

Why is this happening and is there a way in IICS to avoid this? Is it possible to pass in-out parameter values from pipeline to pipeline in the same mapping job and in the same session?

In addition to this, I am aware of passing parameters between differen mappings in a taskflow, but in this case I need a single mapping task because this mapping task will be invoked through **Cloud Integration Hub** (something that unfortunately can't be done with taskflow).

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.